# Infopath 2010 InfoPath cannot load the view. The view may have been modified to contain unsupported HTML such as frames

Tags: infopath

Suddenly, all my infopath 2010 forms are throwing this error when I open them in design mode.

I only use the UI to design forms, no custom HTML.

I think the problem is local to my machine, but I wonder if anyone has seen this before?

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to share my findings on this issue.

I have found that if you resize the Infopath Designer window so that it only covers a quarter of the desktop, the form will then open successfully!

You can then maximise the Infopath Window & work on the form as normal.

I have tried this on a couple of computers & it definitely allows the form to be opened successfully.

I guess it must be some sort of graphics issue or something..?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow, i can't believe that works. What crappy software.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "tablet pc input service" of windows. After that you may be able to open the forms in design mode. It has worked for me.